# Displaying HTML in a JTable

Tags: java, html, swing, jtable

Can someone provide me with an example of how to display HTML in a cell of a JTable?  I know this can be done for other Swing components but I can't seem to figure it out for JTables.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)  SO is not a code factory.

Comment: What do you want to display in HTML? The default cell renderer is a `JLabel` so you can do some basic HTML by wrapping the contents in `<html></html>`.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, you're saying "how do I do X?" is not a valid question? SO is not a "correct my code" factory either - the FAQ says that "...if your question generally covers a specific programming problem...hen you’re in the right place to ask your question!"  **You** may want code with every question but it's not required.

Comment: @Paul  That is a comment I generally reserve for those who claim things like *"I can't seem to figure it out for JTables"*  If they can't seem to figure it out, they must logically have tried some things.  Which leads me to inquire *"What have you tried?"*  So when you challenge *"you're saying "how do I do X?" is not a valid question?"*  My first reaction is *"What post/comment were **you** reading?"*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you remembering to put `<html>` around the HTML markup as per `<html>...</html>`? The default string renderer in a `JTable` uses `JLabel`, so this should work. Just set the String as the cell value.

Answer (score 3):

How to use HTML in Swing components is described in the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html). If you combine this with the [`JTable` tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), and more specifically with the part about the [Editors and renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) and the [custom renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) you should get pretty far.

To summarize all those links: either your `TableModel` contains HTML formatted `String` instances and then all will work with the standard renderer. Otherwise you can adjust the renderer to convert your model values to a HTML string and show those in for example a `JLabel`

Answer (score 0):

Among others, I had this method overridden in my cell renderer label implementation:

```
  @Override
  protected void firePropertyChange(String propertyName, Object oldValue, Object newValue)
  {
    // empty override for performance reasons.
  }
```

Once I removed the override, the HTML rendering started to work.